# Calculating age using a class

Tags: python, function, module, self

I am trying to write code that calculates age using a class, but I am relatively new to modules and classes and I have difficulty assigning the value to `self`.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
from datetime import date

class time:
    def __init__(self,time):
        self.time=time

    def function(self):
        today=date.today()
        birthday=today.year-self.year-((today.month,today.day)<(self.month,self.day))
        return birthday

y=time
print (y.function.datetime.date(1994,4,12))
```

Comment: The `self` in `function` is an **instance** of `class time` not the class itself. You would want to assign something else to it. Functions like you have generally `return` one or more values when called.

Comment: thanks for your response.this is not my original code,it was edited by some one else after i posted it and he changed the name of instance to class.

Comment: jamal: I've put your original code back in (with a few minor cosmetic changes). — which you could have done yourself, btw. Regardless, I still don't understand what you mean about "assigning the value to `self`", so at least that part of my previous comment still applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative way to do it you might find interesting.

```
from datetime import date

class Time:
    def __init__(self, date):
        self.time = date

    def age(self):
        today = date.today()
        date_this_year = date(today.year, self.time.month, self.time.day)
        return today.year - self.time.year - (date_this_year > today)

time = Time(date(1994,4,12))
print(time.age())
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I will recommend you to always start your classes with a capital letter and rename your function with for example the name (calculate_age()).

The final result should look like this :

```
from datetime import datetime, date

class Time:
    def __init__(self, date):
        self.date=date

    def calculate_age(self):
        today = datetime.now()
        return today.year - self.date.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (self.date.month, self.date.day))

time = Time(date(1994,4,12))

print(time.calculate_age())
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver.I also made a mistake during assigning `self values`,i didn't add the `.date` to them.

Comment: No problem about that, I can just recommend you to read a book or watch a video, or anything else to master classes, you didn't understand totally the concepts but you are in the right way ^^